# How to use AWS private application load balancer in aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, aws-vpc

I have a situation to use AWS private(internal-facing) application load balancer (not a network load balancer) in the api gateway. Can anyone please guide me how to use ALB in the api gateway.

Comment: Do anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to integrate API Gateway with a private or internal facing ALB using http api route with private resource integration through a VPC link.

I've done so with an API Gateway --> VPC link --> internal facing ALB --> EC2 cluster with fargate in private subnets

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413951/2948212 for a step by step guide.